# In Excel, trim the last 3 characters and sum all the matching results

Tags: excel

I have a huge `CSV` that contains file locations such as this:

```
\\fileserver1\employees\production team\Reports\surveygroup\WIP 08052011.xls
```

But with all sorts of extensions. I want to be able to, on a separate sheet I have as a report, show a list of all the times a certain file type is used. For example, I want a report page that looks like this:

```
 .JPG    492
 .PDF    567
 .XLS    124
```

Thank you for anyone that can help!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? You might find the function `RIGHT()` and a pivot table useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you already have a distinct list of the extensions?  If you do you can use a wildcard with countif.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*jpg")
```

The * at the beginning will count any items that end with "jpg".  If those items are in a cell you can do the same thing by concatenating a wildcard with a cell value like this.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*" & C1)
```

Comment: This was perfect! I adapted it to 
`=COUNTIF(Result_Summary!A:A,"*jpg")`
That's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find how to combine them together.  But these two formulas will do the trick:

```
=RIGHT(E6,3)
```

Returns the last 3 letter in the cell

```
=COUNTIF(F6:F10,"jpg")
```

Counts up the instances of a given string.